# Answer required for 2 Unix MCQ questions

Tags: linux, unix

I am having two questions on Unix. I am confused which is the correct answer. Can you please help me out with the answers?

1) "Sticky Bit" applied to a file denote which of the following?
a) It would stick around in memory even once its execution is over
b) None of the options provided
c) It would be executed on its own the next time you login
d) No one can remove it

2) What is the size of each entry in inode table?
a) 64 b
b) 64 kB
c) 32 b
d) 32 kB

Comment: Did you google your questions? Read first the wikipage on [sticky bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sticky bit denotes only owner of the file of the file or root user can only delete it. 
   So, as per the option, it will be **Option B**.
2. Each inode entry is 128 bytes which contain metadata, here no options match so far as given.